# Simple dropbox client for windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, dropbox

I am looking for a client for dropbox that doesn't have so much windows integration.

1. Doesn't run in the background.
2. Portable executable.
3. Looks like an ftp client.

I would just use the web interface but it's citing a 300mb file limit.

Comment: Please comment to the reason for the thumb-down. Is software recommendation off topic here?

Comment: Did you research Dropbox clients? I am not aware of any Dropbox client other than the official one.

Comment: @iglvzx, I know there are various clients for Linux. I attempted to find a alternative for windows, but could not. Hence the question.

Comment: Apparently cyberduck has a dropbox plugin, but its a PITA to set up - you need an api key, and i have never got it working. If you did, and you could run it portably, it would meet your needs. IIRC dropbox does not officially support third party clients at this point

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [DropboxPortableAHK](http://nionsoftware.com/dbpahk/overview)?

It's a portable version of Dropbox you can run off a flashdrive.